# RSpec/Rails post test issue with post data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

Rails: 4.1.7

RSpec-rails version: 3.1.0

I am trying to write a request spec to test the `create` action for my `BlogPost` model. RSpec doesn't seem to like the data params that I am trying to pass in because I keep seeing the following error when running the test:

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: blog_post`

RSpec code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe BlogPost do
  let!(:admin_user) { Fabricate(:admin_user) }
  let!(:blog_post) { Fabricate(:blog_post) }
  before { login(admin_user.email, admin_user.password) }

  describe 'POST /admin/blog_posts' do
    before do
      post admin_blog_posts_path, blog_post: {
        body: 'body text',
        title: 'title text',
        cover_image: '/assets/post.png',
        summary: 'cool post bruh',
        live_demo_url: 'livedemo.com',
        live_demo_url_text: 'click here',
        github_source: 'github.com/awesome'
      }
    end

    it 'should redirect to the blog posts index page' do
      expect(response).to redirect_to(admin_blog_posts_path)
      follow_redirect!
    end
  end
end
```

There is something about using the word `blog_post` it doesn't seem to like. Because I tried changing it to an arbitrary word like so and the error went away:

```
post admin_blog_posts_path, someresource: {
  title: 'title text'
}
```

Also I have a `put` request spec, which is also using `blog_post` and that works fine:

```
describe 'PUT /admin/blog_posts/:id' do
    before do
      put admin_blog_post_path(blog_post.id), blog_post: {
        title: 'My new title'
      }
    end

    ...
  end
```

So I'm not really sure why `RSpec` doesn't like my `post admin_blog_posts_path, blog_post ...` syntax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Noob status over here.

In my controller create action I had:

`@blog_post = BlogPost.new(permitted_params)`

It was raising the error because I passed in the entire params so it read `blog_post` as an attribute for the `BlogPost` resource.

The fix: `@blog_post = BlogPost.new(permitted_params[:blog_post])`